# Character @ in a :: literal

Tags: python-sphinx

I am trying to include in my source .rst file literal producing text like:

```
::

  @reboot myscript
```

However `@reboot` appears in boldface. Did not find how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy -- just precede with the following line:

`.. highlight:: none`

Otherwise Sphinx assumes it is Python code (default)!